# Is It Possible To Update A System Image Backup? If So How?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, backup

I'm planning to replace my hard drive soon and want to use a System Image to restore everything.

I have a System Image that I created about a month ago. If it's possible I would like to update the image I already have instead of creating a new one and deleting the old one.

Is it it possible to do so?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: we could add update packages to custermized image. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/add-updates-to-customized-windows-and-winpe-images

Comment: The simplest thing is to create an entirely new image. The tools that *can* update existing images are complex and expensive and usually designed for enterprise or high-value system backup, not for moving data to a new hard drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. No, it's probably not the best solution for what you're trying to accomplish.

The programs can allow for backing up only changed files to image-level backups are complex and expensive and are typically targeted towards enterprise or high-value systems, not a simple personal computer you just need to image for a new hard drive installation.

Add to this that each of these products will use a proprietary format and will NOT be able to use the image you created recently as a starting or reference point. In other words: You'd have to create an entirely new backup image anyways, even if you chose a suitable and capable backup tool.

In fact, many new hard drives come with software that will do the image for you.

I strongly advise that the simplest and easiest thing to do right now is to create a new image backup for the HDD upgrade process.